# Componentart tabstrip only rendering first tab

Tags: asp.net, ajax, componentart

I have a ComponentArt tabstrip. Our firm recently migrated all it's users to IE8. For some reason on some pages the tabstrip only display the first tab now. But on others it renders fine. The code for the tabstrip is virtually identical in all pages, saving things like tab names. Here's an example from a page that only renders the first tab:

```
<ComponentArt:TabStrip ID="tsAdmin" runat="server" MultiPageId="EditUsers" CssClass="TopTabs"
                  DefaultItemLookId="DefaultTabLook"
                  DefaultSelectedItemLookId="SelectedTabLook"
                  DefaultDisabledItemLookId="DisabledTabLook"
                  DefaultGroupTabSpacing="1"
                  ImagesBaseUrl="tabstrip"
                  ScrollingEnabled="false"
                  ScrollLeftLookId="ScrollItem"
                  ScrollRightLookId="ScrollItem"
                  Width="100%" >
                <Tabs>
                    <ComponentArt:TabStripTab runat="server" ID="tab0" Text="Tab 1"></ComponentArt:TabStripTab>
                    <ComponentArt:TabStripTab runat="server" ID="tab1" Text="Tab 2"></ComponentArt:TabStripTab>
                    <ComponentArt:TabStripTab runat="server" ID="tab2" Text="Tab 3"></ComponentArt:TabStripTab>
                    <ComponentArt:TabStripTab runat="server" ID="tab3" Text="Tab 4"></ComponentArt:TabStripTab>
                </Tabs>
                <ItemLooks>
                <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="DefaultTabLook" CssClass="DefaultTab" HoverCssClass="DefaultTabHover" LabelPaddingLeft="10" LabelPaddingRight="10" LabelPaddingTop="5" LabelPaddingBottom="4" LeftIconUrl="tab_left_icon.gif" RightIconUrl="tab_right_icon.gif" HoverLeftIconUrl="hover_tab_left_icon.gif" HoverRightIconUrl="hover_tab_right_icon.gif" LeftIconWidth="3" LeftIconHeight="21" RightIconWidth="3" RightIconHeight="21" />
                  <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="SelectedTabLook" CssClass="SelectedTab" LabelPaddingLeft="10" LabelPaddingRight="10" LabelPaddingTop="4" LabelPaddingBottom="4" LeftIconUrl="selected_tab_left_icon.gif" RightIconUrl="selected_tab_right_icon.gif" LeftIconWidth="3" LeftIconHeight="21" RightIconWidth="3" RightIconHeight="21" />
                  <ComponentArt:ItemLook LookId="ScrollItem" CssClass="ScrollItem" HoverCssClass="ScrollItemHover" LabelPaddingLeft="5" LabelPaddingRight="5" LabelPaddingTop="0" LabelPaddingBottom="0" />
                </ItemLooks>
            </ComponentArt:TabStrip>
```

When I check the page source there are some generated javascript references to the various tabs, but when I check the source code with Firebug only the first tab has any markup references in the HTML. On the pages where the tabs render properly, all tabs are visible in the HTML through Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to delete this question. Turns out the problem was with some javascript I'd written and not the tab strip.